# How to write php within html within php?

Tags: php, html, parsing, escaping

I have recently asked this question, but rather than getting a direct answer, I was shown how to use the ternary operator to simplify my code by substituting if statements inside my html with variables, which I appreciated and put to use - however that also caused other code to be harder to read and ultimately did not teach me to properly escape/parse php in code similar to that below.

So I would love a simple 'show and tell' of how to make the following code parse, thank you:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['myform'])) {
  echo

<form method="POST" action="<?php if (isset($myform_worked)) { echo 'somepath'; } ?>" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

This is what I've tried, but the  line above doesn't parse:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['myform'])) {
  echo

'<form method="POST" action="'<?php if (isset($myform_worked)) { echo 'somepath'; } ?>'" accept-charset="UTF-8">'
```

I have also tried (using double quotes around the php inside :

```
"<?php if (isset($myform_worked)) { echo 'somepath'; } ?>"
```

Please show this nub how to do this, thanks. I do not care if the above code is BAD... I just need to learn how to escape/parse php inside html inside php, thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing like "php inside html inside php". There is PHP inside HTML only

Comment: Hmm, 4 correct answers and some random downvotes?

Comment: 4 answers from someone who didn't read the question I'd say

Comment: The question was, can I put PHP in HTML in PHP. The answer is: yes, if you don't use `<?php` tags but just concatenate the `echo` string. Which is exactly what most of the answers are saying. But my time is too valuable for this discussion, deleted my answer.

Comment: @CompuChip actually the answer is: no, he can't. All your answers are about PHP alone: how to write PHP code itself (string syntax, namely). "foo <bar> $baz </bar>"  by no means is PHP in HTML but merely a php string.

Comment: Deep breath everyone - I really appreciate all the answers... I'm sorry I didn't get to see yours CompuChip, but thanks for answering. I really learned a lot from everyones answers and the mini-debate above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not close the open php-block beforehand. The working Syntax would be like this:

```
<?php
//php code
?>
<!--HTML-Code-->
<?php
?>
```

Or according to your problem:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['myform'])) {
?>

<form method="POST" action="<?php if (isset($myform_worked)) { echo 'somepath'; } ?>" accept-charset="UTF-8">

<?php } //if-closing bracket ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much - this was the quickest/easiest solution!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close PHP tag before entering HTML mode.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, inside php. In php page, adding php code inside the html tags looks like `<?php //your php code here ?>`.

```
         <?php
         if (!isset($_POST['myform'])) {
              echo '<form method="POST" action="'.isset($myform_worked)?'somepath':''.'" accept-charset="UTF-8">';
          }
         ?>
```

HTML+PHP

```
   <?php if (!isset($_POST['myform'])) { ?>
      <form method="POST" action="<?php if (isset($myform_worked)) { echo 'somepath'; } ?>" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Sorry I did not use this as I would have to change too much php that is littered amongst my html (being the nub that I am). However, I did learn from it and will test this in the future, as I can already see a use for it. Thanks again!

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php echo "hello world";?>
```

OR Shorthand

```
<?="hello world"?>
```

Comment: Sorry Dane, this did not answer my question - see above answers for what I required. However, thanks for trying to help me!